# Is it safe to checkout a new git branch during the push of a current branch?

Tags: git, github, push, git-checkout

For example, if I am pushing `master` to a remote repo and it's taking a while, is it safe to open another terminal and do `git checkout secondbranch` so I can start working again? Is the original process doing the push going to be disrupted by the new checkout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be safe, because push is reading from your local repo and writing to the remote, and checkout is reading from your local repo and writing to your workspace.

Nice visualization of what-goes-where:
http://www.ndpsoftware.com/git-cheatsheet.html#loc=local_repo;

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is safe.

Push is separate concept from the working directory and the checked-out branch. You can actually push and fetch from the .git directory of your repo (or any bare repo for that matter). That shows, at a high level, the two aspects of the application are well isolated.

With that being said, always make backups of your data.

Comment: What if you push HEAD? Doing a checkout changes your HEAD. Would it be safe as well?

Comment: Yep. HEAD while be resolved to the actual commit hash, and that never changes. As long as the push is started you'll be fine.